# Use mysqli or PDO instead?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

I just uploaded my very old scripts on my hosting account. When I login to my website, I found this note. I read about mysqli but still don't work on changing Anyone please help!

```
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user_log', '12345'); 
$db = mysql_select_db('name_log',$con);
```

Comment: `mysql` is deprecated as you have read. You need to change it to mysqli or PDO. Have you tried that? ..Also, what "note" did you find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire ext/mysql PHP extension was officially deprecated in **PHP v5.5.0** and removed in **PHP v7**.There are two other MySQL extensions that you can consider: **MySQLi** and **PDO_MySQL**, either of which can be used instead of ext/mysql.
it's possible to suppress deprecation errors by setting error_reporting in php.ini or in your each pages or config file to exclude **E_DEPRECATED.**

`error_reporting = E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED`

or

you can use 
`error_reporting(0)`

Change your code From

`$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user_log', '12345');` 
to

```
$con= mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_database);
```